# How much heat can a Fire Pokemon withstand?

Tags: pokemon

Say that a Fire Pokemon (like a Charizard) is placed inside a box which is heated until it reaches a theoretical infinity. At what point does it 1.) feel pain 2.) burn 3.) die. If anyone has any canonical feats that would answer this, that would be great.

Comment: Not bad :) but looking through the post is not enough i recommend you take the [tour] and visit the [help] on what's good or not on a posted question.

Comment: There’s no such thing as an *average* Charizard!

Comment: Conceivably, Charizard's "fire gland" or mouth, or whatever, and his tail may be the only parts of his body able to withstand that heat. In the games Charizard takes 50% damage to fire attacks, as well as 50% damage to "fighting" attacks. This means that a Karate Chop and a Fire Blast both deal half as much as they would. Half, but not nothing. Given that example, I'd say it takes pain at almost any temperature open flame can exist at, say 1000C in the case of a candle or much less in the case of paper or leaves.

Comment: As explained expertly in http://what-if.xkcd.com/115/ endurance to heat is always related to time and even humans can endure the surface of the sun if the exposure is short enough

Comment: @Gorchestopher H-That could just be game mechanics, however. Magcargo also takes a mere half damage reduction from fire type attacks and as stated by Richard, it Canonically has a body temperature of over 18,000 degrees Farenheit. I can't imagine something with a body temperature that high getting hurt by an attack like ember. Good analysis though and thank you for commenting.

Comment: @firefly17 Just for posterity, Magcargot takes 25% damage from fire, while Charizard takes 50%.

Comment: @Gorchestopher H -My bad, I thought Magcargo was a pure fire type, not fire/rock. Still, the fact that he takes some damage from even weak fire type moves doesn't make much sense to me considering his body temperature. Also, Groudon takes 100% fire damage (50% in primal form, the same as Charizard). This is despite the fact that according to the Pokedex, "it sleeps in magma underground". This is best demonstrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbUQ2t-zRtI#t=52). Going off of in-game fire resistance alone,if Groudon can comfortably stand in magma, so can Charizard.

Comment: This answer really depends on the Pokemon involved. Moltres is depicted to live inside of a volcano, but I'd hesitate to say that *every* fire Pokemon could do so.

Comment: Unrelated really but u know, a human can withstand over 200 degrees, in fact over 212 which is boiling point of water. How can this be? It has to be "dry heat" (like in Phoenix) which affects conduction. Of course, immersed in water anywhere near that temp is nearly instant death. Similarly it's no fun to walk around in 35 degree weather naked, but try water that cold and you will also die very fast. Perhaps this has some bearing on Pokemon -- I hope it does...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can't think of an example of *maximum* temperature but we can establish some baselines;

In the original Pokemon Red pokedex (for the Gameboy) it stated that:

> Charizard, the Flame Pokémon. **Charizard's powerful flame can melt
>   absolutely anything.**

Taking this at face value, (and given that the element with the highest melting point is Tungsten) this would be 3500°C.

In one episode of the anime series ([Volcanic Panic](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP059)), Charizard and Magmar fight. Both end up covered in molten magma (approx 1000°C) and both attempt to flame each other with flames that are described as being similarly hot, with **no effect**.

---

In ["Some Like It Hot!" (Magcargot! Getting the Hot Heart!!)](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP240), Ash and crew encounter the Magcargo. The [pokedex entry on Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magcargo_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Biology) describes it thusly:

> Magcargo's body temperature (18,000°F) is much higher than the
>   temperature of the surface of the sun (9,940°F).

When Ash encounters one, there's a brief discussion of which Pokemon he could use to attack it. Sensibly speaking, we can assume that Charizard would be able to resist it since Ash doesn't mention its weakness to the temperatures it can generate.

Comment: **<removed comments>** Further discussion should probably go to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The _element_ with the highest melting point is Tungsten. There are plenty of materials with higher melting points. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/16640

Comment: Probably worth being another question, but if Magargot is hotter than the sun shouldn't everything and everyone around it burst into flames just by being near it?

Comment: @TheUnknownDev not only that, you would be able to see the critter even with your eyes closed. At least for the fraction of a second it would take for your retinas to be permanently damaged beyond repair.

Answer (score 3):

This is never mentioned. It is not known how true Pokedex entries are. It can be assumed that since all Pokemon take damage from fire-type attacks unless they have the ability Flash Fire, that they can't take arbitrarily high temperatures of heat.

Comment: The people collecting the data are a bunch of 10-year-old kids after all.

Answer (score 1):

Unless they have an ability such as Flash Fire, fire Pokémon take damage from all direct fire attacks.

The weakest fire Pokémon we have numbers for (that I can find) is Magby, according to it's Pokédex entry it [exhales flames of 1,100 degrees F](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-sm/240.shtml). Comparing stats, Vulpix has a lower Special attack stat than Magby and so likely has a weaker flame still, not to mention the non-fire types who can learn fire attacks. As Magby is the weakest we have numbers for however, it's a good benchmark.

The lowest temperature flame that we know almost all fire Pokémon take damage from is Magby's **1,100°F (593°C)** Fire Spin attack. (In the video games)

Answer (score 0):

Well, going on the Pokemon Red Pokedex entry for Charizard, if its flames can truly melt anything based on that entry, it would, AT MINIMUM, have to be 3942 °C, or 7128 °F, the temperature for the compound with the highest melting point, Tantalum hafnium carbide (Pronounced: TAN-tal-um HALF-knee-um CAR-bide). Going for the ELEMENT with the highest melting point, Tungsten, Charizard's flame would have to be at least 3,422°C, or 6,191°F, which is hotter than THC. If anyone can find something higher than that, I'm a potato.

Answer (score 0):

If we are only talking fire-type starter Pokemon, Then Delphox and Skeledirge both take the gold medal, Both managing to reach a temperature surpassing 5,400 Degrees Fahrenheit (3000 Celcius)

For proof:

**Delphox's pokedex entry from Y/ AS:**

Using psychic power, it generates a fiery vortex of 5,400 degrees Fahrenheit, incinerating foes swept into this whirl of flame.

**Delphox's Pokedex Entry from Violet:**

It controls flames telekinetically, trapping its foes in a fiery vortex surpassing 5,400 degrees Fahrenheit and burning them to a crisp.

**Skeledirge's Pokedex entry from Violet:**

Skeledirge’s gentle singing soothes the souls of all who hear it. It burns its enemies to a crisp with flames of over 5,400 degrees Fahrenheit.

To put that into context, 5,400 degrees Fahrenheit is over half the temperature of the sun's surface (10,340 degrees Fahrenheit (From Nasa.gov)). 5,400 degrees Fahrenheit is enough to vaporize or liquefy most of the periodic table of elements. The only elements that can survive (remain a solid from) a blast from Delphox or Skeledirge are Carbon (Obviously), Tantalum, Tungsten, Rhenium, and Osmium.

For fun, What would be Delphox's or Skeledirge's Temperature if they were to be GMaxed? To figure this out, I've calculated the average growth in size from all of the GMax Pokemon. I did this assuming that the temperature was proportional to the size of the Pokemon at stake. The average size multiplier was around 26x. Using the assumption that Temperature was proportional to the Pokemon size, Delphox's and Skeledirge's GMax temperature is:

5400*26 = 140,400 Degrees Fahrenheit!

That is almost (or possibly over) 14x Hotter than the surface of the sun.
Everything would be vaporized In their path!

Bonus:
Come up with a Gmax design and Gmax move for Skeledirge and Delphox

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Where exactly are you getting your sources from?

Comment: @fez - Likely https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Delphox_(Pok%C3%A9mon) based on the annotations

Comment: Note that it's been far too long, but IIRC effective temperature doesn't scale linearly as energy...